# How to to reuse content between two DITA maps and keep the folder structure

Tags: dita, oxygenxml

I am using Oxygen XML Author and I have two maps that have a lot of similar content. Right now, the content is not reused, but it would be great to make it reusable. The maps are called `InstallGuide.ditamap` and `AdminGuide.ditamap` they are stored on the disk with the following hierarchy:

```
common/
  InstallGuide.ditamap
Product/
  ProductFeatures/
    MainProduct/
      AdminGuide.ditamap
```

Is there a way to put a new parent map to disk root and include my other two maps in it and make content reusable? Right now if I try, the maps are included, but only as non-editable references so I can't set up any reuse and can't set profiling attributes.

Why do I need profiling?
Since the maps are two different documents I want to be able to profile them from the parent map. But I want to also be able to reuse content from one map to another. Moreover, I would want to keep the folder structure unchanged. Is that possible?

I can't get my head around the solution for my "wants". Maybe someone can propose a better way to achieve the goal, I would appreciate that.